# Where to place a configuration file outside application war

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I have a `Spring` application that at startup needs to read some basic properties from a file but nothing sensitive (timeout values, directory locations, etc.). It needs to be edited before starting the application depending on the desired target server.

My first easy idea was to place the file under home target server, then load it into `Spring`

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/config/application.properties" />.
```

I found other sources mentioning the usage of `System properties` or `JBoss modules`.

Are there any advantages/disadvantages for using one on another? What else should I consider when choosing the appropriate one in my case?

Comment: First and maybe a stupid question: Why do you use Spring when you have Java EE in JBoss? But to come to your question if you use system properties they can be changed during runtime and will be available immediately. But because you use Spring it dosen't matter. So all tree solutions are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The choice of Spring was decided on a lot of factors like background knowledge, consistency with previous projects, integration with other frameworks and in the end personal preference. In my case, changing properties during run time would not be a good idea as I need a shared location on the disk where I can create/edit/delete some files and it has to be the same while the server is running.

Comment: Ok. But do you need any features of JBoss then? Maybe you could use Tomcat instead?

Comment: No, JBoss is a requirement.

Comment: In that case go with your proposed solution. <context:property-placeholder location="file:${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/config/application.properties" />.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding Spring looks by default properties file in your app directory, or you can register a properties file with XML config or Java config (Annotations):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:my.properties"/>
Then you refer to the properties in your beans:
@Component
class MyClass {
  @Value("${my.property.name}")
  private String[] myValues;
}
```

or

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/myco/app.properties")
public class AppConfig {
   @Autowired
   Environment env;

   @Bean
   public TestBean testBean() {
       TestBean testBean = new TestBean();
       testBean.setName(env.getProperty("testbean.name"));
       return testBean;
   }
}
```

the properties file can be updated at any time (just stoping serv) in the apps server, tomcat, jboss, etc.
note sure if that's what you want,

Comment: I already know this, I was looking for a technical argument for choosing among the available solutions.